# Spring - AutoWired object NullPointerExpection, Sequence Generator

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, spring-mvc

We have the following error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at sequence.MySequence.generate(MySequence.java:23)
```

My Sequence Generator

```
    @Component
    public class MySequence implements IdentifierGenerator {

    @Autowired
    SequenceDAO sequenceDAO;

    public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object object)
            throws HibernateException {

        <-- sequenceDAO.getNextValue -->

        return sequenceNextValue;
    }
    }
```

SequenceDAO

```
    public interface SequenceDAO {

    Long getNextValue();

    }
```

SequenceDAOImpl

```
    @Repository
    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public class SequenceDAOImpl implements SequenceDAO {

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Long getNextValue() {

        <-- getNextValue -->

        return nextValue;
    }
    }
```

Config

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="controller" />
<context:component-scan base-package="dao" />
<context:component-scan base-package="service" />
<context:component-scan base-package="sequence" /> <-- is there MySequence
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Rest as Controller, Service, DAO work without problems - @autowired works as it should. Only here I don't know why it happens.

All it needs for the sequence generator (Oracle Database makes id as a String; 
therefore I can't use the generator directly from the database)

```
@Id
@GenericGenerator(name="seqid", strategy="sequence.MySequence")
@GeneratedValue(generator="seqid")
@Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 32)
public String getId() {
    return this.id;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please show the stacktrace and the missing code from `MySequence.generate()`.

Answer (score 3):

The generator class is instanciated by Hibernate, so it is not managed by spring and no injection occurs. You will have to implement directly the code from your `SequenceDAO` in the method `generate()` (you receive a session in the parameters from which you can execute queries) or find a mean to access the spring content through a static method and get your `SequenceDAO` from it.